# Difference between the testnet and the devnet when it comes to response in NFT data

Tags: multiversx

I found the difference between devnet and testnet. The NFTs minted using the same SC and endpoint:

- **devnet**: https://devnet-explorer.multiversx.com/nfts/FFFF-364539-03
- **testnet**: https://testnet-explorer.multiversx.com/nfts/RTYU-c271dc-15

The testnet is missing: 'attributes', 'uris', 'creator' fields. It looks like all which are ManagedBuffers, ManagedVec, ManagesAddress, etc.

Is this something on the API side?
Smart Contract transactions executed without errors.

Answer (score 1):

The current T1.3.5.0 node version used on the testnet is employing some new optimization features that are not yet available on the devnet/mainnet, thus, some services might experience slight hiccups because of this, like this unfortunate case.

The overall idea is that the returned data should be consistent between the nets and this is definitely an issue somewhere, but the MultiversX team is currently investigating it.
So it should be back to the normal expected behavior soon.